# scripting insertion of variable to config file

Tags: bash, sed

As part of a post-preseeding script, I want to disable ipv6.

In `/etc/default/grub` I want to change this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINX=""
```

so that it reads:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"
```

Which can be done with:

```
sed -i "s/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=\"\"/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=\"ipv6.disable=1\"/" /etc/default/grub
```

But sed won't match if GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX already has arguments in it.

How can I add the parameter while preserving any existing arguments (if any) ?

Comment: So if empty, fill with "ipv6...". Otherwise, keep the value?

Comment: Maybe you should try GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX instead of GRUB_CMD_LINE_LINUX (delete the underscore between CMD and LINE).

Comment: thanks uzolt, just a typo.  @fedorqui, no, if there's a value already there, keep it and add ipv6.disable=1 inside the quotes, if there's no value, just add it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are nuking the entire line. Try

```
s/GRUB_CMD_LINE_LINUX=\"/GRUB_CMD_LINE_LINUX=\"ipv6.disable=1XXX/
```

to insert your assignment to the front and replace XXX with the character used as a separator. Perhaps ;. Alternatively

```
s/(GRUB_CMD_LINE_LINUX=[^\"]*)\"$/\1XXXipv6.disable=1"/
```

to insert at the end of the line. ie after all existing params. You may have to escape the parenthesis and/or " in the second version.

Solved with:

```
sed "s/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=\"\(.*\)\"/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=\"\1 ipv6.disable=1\"/" /etc/default/grub
```